# Using transaction in SQL Server calling stored procedure in another server

Tags: sql-server

I want to execute an stored procedure in `Server1.DB1`, this stored procedure will execute inside another stored procedure using dynamic SQL, it will be in `Server1.DB2`.

I need to use begin/end transaction to make sure everything is executed or everything fail.

The question is: will the transaction work in this case using dynamic SQL pointed to a the different database?

Like

```
BEGIN TRANSACT
    --Set Status to "In Progress"   
    SET @Qry = N'EXEC '+ @DB2 + '.[dbo].[StatusUpdate] @Id, @Status'
    SET @QryParams = N'@Id INT, @Status INT'

    EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @Qry, 
        @QryParams,
        @Id = @Id,
        @Status = @InProgress

   INSERT DATA LOCALLY IN A TABLE

   UPDATE DATA LOCALLY IN A TABLE

END TRANSACT
```

I'm using SQL Server 2014.

Comment: Please post the specific version of RDBMS and what you have tried

Comment: What exactly is your question? You might have a question mark (`?`) at the end of that sentence, but it's actually not asking a question. Think you need to reword and elaborate here.

Comment: Wouldn't this be easier to just test it instead of posting a question?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on `REMOTE_PROC_TRANSACTIONS` [definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-remote-proc-transactions-transact-sql):

> Specifies that when a local transaction is active, executing a remote
>   stored procedure starts a Transact-SQL distributed transaction managed
>   by Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MS DTC).

If it's ON:

> The instance of SQL Server making the remote stored procedure call is
>   the transaction originator and controls the completion of the
>   transaction. When a subsequent COMMIT TRANSACTION or ROLLBACK
>   TRANSACTION statement is issued for the connection, the controlling
>   instance requests that MS DTC manage the completion of the distributed
>   transaction across the computers involved.

Otherwise remote stored procedure calls are not made part of a local transaction.

Several important notes:

- Using distributed transaction is risky thus should be carefully used.
- This feature is deprecated.